# Mapbox free camera "look at" with adjustable height

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to change the camera 'look at' height on the mapbox scene which include 3d objects
https://srvlc.sse.codesandbox.io/ or https://codesandbox.io/s/srvlc

You can see if you maximum zoom-out, camera target height is 0, I mean directly on the map, which is fine for small 3d objects, but not for big. I added an issue on their git too for a feature request, but meanwhile I'm curious if there is a workaround or something which I missed

I tried with `map.transform._centerAltitude` which seems to work for zoom, but broke pann & rotate controls

Comment: Your codesandbox is not opening for me. Can you edit your question, and post the relevant code?

Comment: I edited it, sorry for this